# Rails Error When Launching Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

When I try to launch my local rails server I get the following error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Frank/Dropbox/DePaul/Year 2/Winter/IT 232/divdev232/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I'm just Confused in what any of that means, or how to fix it, as I'm still getting familiar with rails. Here's my current Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'

# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more:   https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger   console
gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
# Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %>    anywhere in the code.
gem 'web-console'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution:

Firstly uninstall bcrypt and bcrypt-ruby by running these two commands:

1. `gem uninstall bcrypt` and `gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby`
2. Install it again with `gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby`
3. In your Gemfile write `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.5', :require => 'bcrypt'`
4. Run `bundle install`

Comment: Do I just add the new line to my Gemfile or do i replace the current bcrypt line

Comment: Change line in gemfile and run `bundle install`

Comment: Ya, none of it fixed it

Comment: when you run `bundle install`, does that run properly?

Answer (score 1):

Update Gemfile to :

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.1.rc1', :require => 'bcrypt'
```

Comment: Does that replace the current bcrypt line?:

    gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

Comment: which OS you used?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Comment: Try to install missed lib sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev libgmp3-dev